# Toggle between "\n" and "<br>"

Tags: javascript, jquery

The content of `#comment`

```
  <p id="comment">
    Here<br>
    it<br>
    is
  </p>

  <button id="view">Edit</button>
```

should be made editable by a user and the line breaks `<br>` should switch to `\n` for the textarea.

After the user edits it, the line breaks should be switched again to `<br>`.

I was hoping that this solve the problem:

```
$(document).on("click","#view",function() {
   var $comment = $('#comment');
   var $content = $comment.text().trim().replace("<br>", "\n",  "g");       
   $comment.replaceWith("<textarea name='text' id='textarea'>" + $content + "</textarea>");   
   $('#view').replaceWith('<button id="save">Save</button>');    
});

$(document).on("click","#save",function() {
   var $content = $('#textarea').val().replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
   $('#textarea').replaceWith("<p id='comment'>" + $content + "</p>");
   $('#save').replaceWith('<button id="view">Edit</button>');
});
```

If one clicks Edit -> Save then everything seems to work. But if one hits  edit again, the line breaks are gone:

[image]

Here is a [jFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Elenktik/2tbngdvm/).

Where are the line breaks gone after hitting the button twice?

Comment: @Learner yes to render the line breaks in HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Code:

```
var $content = $('#textarea').val().replace(/(\n)/g, "$1<br />");
```

### Why does this work?

You're effectively replacing the newline character with `<br/>` -but you're forgetting that `textarea` **needs** the newline character to determine whether or not there is a break in the line. You're performing a one-way transformation, after which, the original text isn't properly formatted. Instead of replacing the newline character, simply add `<br />` to the end of that line.

Alternatively you could write code to replace your `<br />` with newline characters upon entering `edit` mode, but you can't use `.text` to do this, as this only grabs actual text, not elements.

---

### Code Snippet:

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $(".pure")

$(document).on("click","#view",function() {
   var $comment = $('#comment');
   var $content = $comment.text().trim();   
   $comment.replaceWith("<textarea name='text' id='textarea'>" + $content + "</textarea>");   
   $('#view').replaceWith('<button id="save">Save</button>');    
});

$(document).on("click","#save",function() {

// CHANGED LINE
   var $content = $('#textarea').val().replace(/(\n)/g, "$1<br />");
// ^^^

$('#textarea').replaceWith("<p id='comment'>" + $content + "</p>");
   $('#save').replaceWith('<button id="view">Edit</button>');
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p id="comment">Here<br>
  it<br>
  is</p>
  <br>
  <button id="view">Edit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow it works! But I am still confused. Whenn I press "edit" the <br>'s are replaced with "\n" so that it can be used by the text area. Why is this working when I press the button the first time but not working after pressing it twice?

Comment: @Adam Because when you transform to `<br />` the first time, you're removing any `\n` - when you go to replace them back, you're only grabbing the `text` of the element, not the `html`. There is no `<br />` to replace because it's not `text`. Does that make sense? :)

Comment: oh thats the problem! I should have used `$comment.html().trim().replace(/<br>/g, "\n");` instead.... I see now. Thank you.

Comment: Your solution also covers the case when you have  a text mixed with  `<br>` and linebreaks.

Comment: Also in your solution one just need to use `var $content = $comment.text().trim()` instead of  `var $content = $comment.text().trim().replace("<br>", "\n",  "g"); `

Comment: @Adam Yep, I noticed that after the fact :) Good catch!

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use split/join rather than the replace.  This answer also adds the `\n` to the join of the `<br>` to fix the original issue.

```js
$(document)
  .on("click", "#view", function() {
    var $comment = $('#comment');
    var content = $comment.text().trim().split('<br>').join('\n');
    
    $comment.replaceWith("<textarea name='text' id='textarea'>"+ content +"</textarea>");
    $('#view').replaceWith('<button id="save">Save</button>');
  })
  .on("click", "#save", function() {
    var content = $('#textarea').val().split('\n').join('<br>\n');
    
    $('#textarea').replaceWith("<p id='comment'>"+ content +"</p>");
    $('#save').replaceWith('<button id="view">Edit</button>');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="comment">
    Here<br>
    it<br>
    is
  </p>

  <button id="view">Edit</button>
```